# voice recording in android

Tags: android

I have microphone instead of phone. So it will throws SD card is removed error. What can i do? How can i change the path? and is it possible in windows? please help me as soon as possible.
my code is on http://www.benmccann.com/blog/android-audio-recording-tutorial/comment-page-2/#comment-34668

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [sdcard emulation support](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#sdcard) in android emulator.

Comment: please give the steps or procedure for Creat SD card image because i don't know how to open console and write commands.thanks in advance.

Comment: Press Start -> Run. Enter "cmd". Press ok. Here is your console.

Comment: That is i know but commands of android emulator can run on this console?

Comment: of course. you just should run it under the /tools directory of your sdk.